# Can Jackson handle serialize and deserialize to java Object type

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

I have this structure

```
 List<Map<String, Object>>
```

or can wrap it

```
   public static  class TestWrapper {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list;

    public TestWrapper() {
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Map<String, Object>> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
   }
```

How would Jackson know to deSerialize the value into what Type of objects into the Map value? If it is configurable, how do I config it like using annotaions?

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain how it works using below classes and example JSON string. Let assume, that we have two classes like below:

```
class TestWrapper<T> {

    private List<Map<String, T>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, T>>();

    public List<Map<String, T>> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Map<String, T>> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

class Entity {

    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And below JSON string as an input:

```
{
  "list" : [ {
    "entity" : {
      "id" : 0
    }
  } ]
}
```

Now when we try to deserialize above JSON using below code we will see that Jackson deserialize unknown type into `Map` class:

```
TestWrapper<?> result = mapper.readValue(json, TestWrapper.class);
System.out.println(result.getList().get(0).get("entity").getClass());
```

Above program prints:

```
class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

If you want to define the type of the `Map` value, you have to build it with `TypeFactory` and provide into JSON deserialization process.

```
TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
JavaType type = typeFactory.constructParametricType(TestWrapper.class, Entity.class);

TestWrapper<Entity> result = mapper.readValue(json, type);
System.out.println(result.getList().get(0).get("entity").getClass());
```

Above program prints:

```
class your.package.Entity
```

As you can see, you can provide generic type providing complex `JavaType` object into deserialization process.

Comment: In my use case, the type of the value in the map is not defined. The map is returned by another method which could put either Long, String or Double in the map value. Any suggestions.